# Open app facebook / twitter app from Cordova

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

What I'm doing is a login with social networks, this works very well but I have a doubt. I leave pictures of what I do and what I'm getting to be a little more understanding. I am using js library OpenFB.js. With twitter even I can not do much but what matters to me most is that if you can do this.

This is what happens is my application :

[image: 1]

This is what I would like to happen, to open the application installed.

[image: 2]

Comment: There could be two things here:
1. You want to see the second screen without seeing the first one. OR
2. User needs to login each time the application is relaunched.
Which one is it?

Comment: I need the option 1. View the second screen without the former.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already logged into Facebook, you will not see the screen on the first image otherwise the screen will appear. Based on the images that you have posted, in order to see the screen on the second image, you have to be logged in. The second screen is the new login flow of Facebook where you can look at the permissions the app is requesting for and if you tap on the edit link, you can refuse certain permissions that your app is asking.
Note that once you grant these permissions, you may no longer see this screen until you remove the app from your Facebook settings.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. I if I am connected to my facebook account but still the first screen appears. It can be any type of configuration or ionic phonegap my application? Probably the library I'm using (OpenFB.js) will have any parameter to open from the application and not from a navigation screen.

Comment: It seems like the user is getting logged out. You'll need to check the OpenFB.js library that you are using, the issue might be there.